# Permission Denied When Writing/Deleting Despite Proper Permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions

First off, yes the parent directory has correct permissions.  Now that that's out of the way, here's the deal.

My users cannot write or rm from `/mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/`

All users are members of the sftpusers group.  Every directory leading to `02-04-02-10` have the same permissions.  Every user can write/rm a file/directory in EVERY directory except if the file/directory is in the `02-04-02-10` directory.

```
$tree -Rpg /mnt/file-server
/mnt/file-server/
├── [drwsrws--- sftpuser]  reports
│   ├── [drwsrws--- sftpuser]  vendor
│   │   ├── [drwsrws--- sftpuser] client
│   │   │   └── [drwsrws--- sftpuser]  2018
│   │   │       ├── [drwsrws--- sftpuser]  02-04-02-10
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Fast_Track_Instock.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Forecast_and_Inventory_Planning.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  parent_asi.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Sales_and_Inventory_Product_Details_Manufacturer.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Sales_and_Inventory_Product_Details_Sourcing.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Sales_Diagnostic_Ordered_Revenue.csv
│   │   │       │   ├── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Sales_Diagnostic_Shipped_Cogs.csv
│   │   │       │   └── [-rw-rw---- sftpuser]  Sales_Diagnostic_Shipped_Revenue.csv

$lsattr /mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/ | grep 02-04
-------------e-- ./02-04-02-10

$stat /mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/
  File: ‘02-04-02-10/‘
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 97eh/2430d  Inode: 15335547    Links: 2
Access: (2770/drwsrws---)  Uid: ( 2001/  fps)   Gid: ( 1006/sftpusers)
Access: 2018-03-19 10:03:34.657116835 -0600
Modify: 2018-03-19 10:03:43.743147764 -0600
Change: 2018-03-19 17:40:03.574287737 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Root can write/rm files, no prob.

Here is an example of a user and the attempt to touch a file:

`id -a uid=3009(seanhadmin) gid=3009(seanhadmin) groups=3009(seanhadmin),1006(sftpusers)`

`touch /mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/foo touch: cannot touch ‘/mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/foo’: Permission denied`

```
$df -h | grep file-server
/dev/md126      4.0T  1.3T  2.6T  33% /mnt/file-server
```

What in the world am I missing?  I have even rebooted the server out of sheer desperation (of course it didn't fix it).

## UPDATE

So I found something screwy with my ACLs.

Here is what a good ACL looks like:

```
$getfacl 01-07-01-13/
 file: 01-07-01-13/
 owner: fps
 group: sftpusers
 flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:sftpusers:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Here's `02-04-02-10`

```
getfacl 02-04-02-10/
 file: 02-04-02-10/
 owner: fps
 group: sftpusers
 flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:2000:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:sftpusers:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

No matter what I tried, I could not get it to update correctly.  As a workaround, I moved the directory to a different filesystem then moved it back and then corrected the permission/ownership again.

If anyone has a solution for why the ACL wouldn't update, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Could we see it failing for a regular user?  Perhaps the output of `id -a` followed by `touch /mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/foo`?

Comment: There's also an inconsistency in what you post above: `/mnt/file-server/reports/vendor/client/2018/02-04-02-10/` has mode 6770 in the `tree` output but mode 2770 in the `stat` output, which makes me concerned that we're not getting a comprehensive, self-consistent picture of what's going on (ie, these data are not all from the same time).

Comment: @MadHatter Corrected permissions in original post.  I copied the output from an old buffer history and didn't get my changes copied.

Comment: Please, cut-and-paste updates to your question *into your question*, don't post them as comments.  Can you show us what happened when you tried to `setfacl` 02-04-02-10, and failed?

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry for my bad form.  I will update the post.  No errors when running `setfacl`.  It behaved as if it worked.

Comment: But the `getfacl` immediately afterwards suggested that it had not?  I'd like to **see** what you're doing; **show, not tell**.  The ACL on the "bad" directory denies write to members of the `sftpusers` group (whilst also allowing it) so this seems a good line of enquiry.  Oh, and if I haven't been clear, you seem to be doing most of the work of solving your problem yourself: congratulations, these are the best learning experiences!

Comment: Patience brother, I can only repair my past sins and update the post so quickly ;-) <edit> actually I can't, after my workaround the original dir got rm'd.  Will have to just mark this as resolved.

Comment: With respect, and just so you know, the local etiquette is that if someone tries to help you, and leads you to an answer, you confirm it works in comments and let *them* write it up, so they can get the answer bonus.  However, it's not a big deal, and I'm very glad you have a workaround.  Now go find the person who rm'ed the directory and tear their kneecaps off, since they ruined the whole investigation <grin>!  (And don't forget to accept your own answer when you can, to put the question to bed.)

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you for explaining.  I have not read anything about the etiquette here so if it is implied, I certainly haven't understood it.  I have removed my answer so that you may present the answer here.

Comment: That's really kind of you, but seriously, don't sweat it.  You documented your workaround very nicely, I really think you should undelete it and (when you can) accept it (by clicking the "tick" outline next to it).  You pretty much solved your own problem - all I did was ask a few leading questions - so I'm very happy to congratulate you on an excellent second question, and leave the credit to you.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was to copy the parent directory to the problem directory to another filesystem then copy it back into place and correct the permissions/ownership.

I wasn't able to troubleshoot the setfacl issue as the problem dirs were rm'd.

If anyone is curious, the commands I ran were:

`$setfacl -Rd --set u:fps:rwx 02-04-02-10
$setfacl -Rd --set g:sftpusers:rwx 02-04-02-10
$setfacl -Rdm o::0 02-04-02-10`